# Adding an angle on the image using css

Tags: html, css, user-interface, canvas, svg

How to get the angle that we see in the image[Trying to create an angle in the image which will reside inside a div element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqTTS.png)

Comment: Post the code you use if you want to get a proper answer

Comment: how ? with css pseudo elements

Comment: A point has `{x,y}`. You have two points `p1` and `p2`. The bearing (angle from 3 o'clock) is `bearing = Math.atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x);` which is in radians that is converted to deg by multiplying by `180 / PI` or 57.2958

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this effect by using an `::after` pseudo-element with a `skew` transform applied to it.

**Working Example:**

```css
body {
background-color: rgb(191, 191, 191);
}

div {
position: relative;
width: 300px;
height: 180px;
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
border: 12px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

img {
display: block;
float: left;
width: 160px;
height: 180px;
}

div::after {
content: '';
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 100px;
z-index: 0;
width: 80px;
height: 180px;
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
transform: skew(-20deg);
}

div p {
position: relative;
z-index: 12;
margin-left: 156px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<img src="http://placekitten.com/g/160/180" alt="Kitten" />
<p>More div content...</p>
<p>More div content...</p>
<p>More div content...</p>
<p>More div content...</p>
</div>
```